# Value is not show when I create a gauge dynamically with justgage plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, gauge, justgage

I'm trying to add gauges dynamically and actually it works but not with the expected behavior, the graphics are shown but the value is 0 even when the graph shows that is not 0, my gauges will be show in a onclick event the divs and the gauges are created in a ajax request.

```
function getLocationsGauge(row, countryId) {
var chartsDataTemp;
var requestData = {
    countryId: $("#hCountryName" + countryId).val()
};
$("div").removeClass("blurELearning");
$("#gg" + countryId).addClass("blurELearning");

$.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    dataType: 'json',
    contentType: 'application/json',
    url: '../XXX/GetLocations',
    async: false,
    data: requestData,
    success: function (chartsdata) {
        chartsDataTemp = chartsdata;
        $(".location").remove();
        $("#divLocations").remove();
        var count = chartsdata.length / 6;
        $('#countryGraphs  section:eq(' + (row) + ')').after('<div id="divLocations" class="card card-info"><div class="card-header"><strong class="header-block">' + $("#hCountryName" + countryId).val() + '</strong></div></div>');
        for (var i = 0; i <= count; i++) {
            $('#divLocations').append('<section id="location' + i + '" class="section location"><div id="rowLocation' + i + '" class="row"></div></section>');
            for (var j = i * 6; j < (i + 1) * 6; j++) {
                $('#rowLocation' + i).append('<div class="col-md-2"><div id= "ggLocation' + (j + 1) + '" ></div ></div >');
            }
        }

        for (var i = 0; i < chartsdata.length; i++) {

            var limit = Number(chartsdata[i].total) * 0.8;
            var total = Number(chartsdata[i].total);
            var approved = Number(chartsdata[i].approved);
            var name = chartsdata[i].location;
            var percentage = approved * 100 / total;
            percentage = parseFloat(Math.round(percentage * 100) / 100).toFixed(2)
            var x = "ggLocation" + (i + 1);
            objectsLocation[i] = new JustGage({
                id: x,
                value: approved,
                min: 0,
                max: total,
                gaugeWidthScale: 1,
                counter: true,
                hideInnerShadow: true,
                title: name + ' ' + percentage + '%',
                label: "approved",
                levelColors: ["#a9d70b", "#ffd6b6", "#fe9e50"],
                levelColorsGradient: true,
                pointer: true,
                pointerOptions: {
                    toplength: 1,
                    bottomlength: -40,
                    bottomwidth: 6,
                    color: '#8e8e93'
                }
            });

        }


    },
    complete: function () {

    },
    error: function () {
        alert("Error loading data for location! Please try again.");
    }
});}
```

[image: Graph result]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a lot of effort I decide to modify the html code directly with javascript.
After creating the object (JustGage) in the for I accessed the span object which contains the text and modified the value

```
var list = document.getElementById(x);   
var list2 = list.childNodes[0];
list2.childNodes[6].childNodes[0].innerHTML = approved;
```